# Regex script remove - Easy

Tags: regex

Can anybody help me with a regex

I am trying to remove everything between `<Script ?????>` and `</script>`

I am using asp and visualscript

```
replace(/< script.*?>*?< \/script>/ig, '');
```

This should work (I think) but it is not working for me, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Update:

I have done it like this and it now removes < script>content

> replace(/< script.*?>[\s\S]*?< /script>/ig, '')

but if I have < script language="">content< /script> it does not work? the script is on multilines as well

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
replace(/<\s*script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\s*\/script>/ig, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

I notice a couple of things in addition to the missing dot pointed out by Benjamin Ortuzar.

In your original regex, "`/< script.*?>*?< \/script>/ig`", there are spaces included after the opening angle brackets; whitespace is significant in regexes, so you'll probably need to remove those.

Also, you'll also need to add the s modifier to activate "single-line mode", which means that newline characters will be matched by dot.

So we end up with:

```
/<script.*?>.*?<\/script>/igs
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem has many side effects and is not easy to solve. You must remove the whole text between the `<script>` tags, even the lines that contains some like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--
document.write("<script>function f(){var a=new Array(10000);f();}();</script>")
//--></script>
```

Also, you must consider that removing the scripting could broke the webpage, so you must replace every event handler hooked to HTML elements, e.g.

```
<BODY onload="return f();">
...
<img src="asdf.gif" onmouseover="return f();">
...
<a href="javascript:void(f());">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<startTag><\s*script[^>]*>)(?<content>[\s\S]*?)(?<endTag><\s*/script[^>]*>)
```

This will allow you to not only find the script tags, but also return them as named groups so for example:

```
<p> some text and maybe an image <img src="http://pathtoimage/image.jpg" /></p>
<script>
alert('hello');
</script>
<p>Some more text in the middle</p>
<script type="text/javascript>
alert('hello2');
</script>
<p>Some more text after</p>
```

will return 2 matches with 3 groupings in each match:

Match 1

1. `<script>`
2. alert('hello');
3. `</script>`

Match 2

1. `<script type="text/javascript>`
2. alert('hello2');
3. `</script>`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like:

```
/(<script>)(.*)(<\/script>)/\1\2/gi
```

Comment: Hi jskaggz thanks for the reply - the script gives me an error with the 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

```
replace(/<script[^>]*>.*?<\/script>/igs, '');
```

You missed a dot ;)